# case calculation result is correct update table from a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use CASE and see whether the columns = total then update a table with todays date.

```
UPDATE dbo.Audit 
       SET AUD_CloseDate =
       CASE
       WHEN Scored + NA = Total THEN GETDATE()
```

At the end I want to see if col1 + col2 = col3, if so then update my column to todays date, and if there is a date already then do nothing.

Scored + NA = Total <---- they are from a temp table

Answer (score 0):

You were almost ready:

```
UPDATE dbo.Audit 
SET AUD_CloseDate = CASE
                        WHEN Scored + NA = Total THEN GETDATE() 
                    END
WHERE AUD_CloseDate IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks and if `Scored`, `NA`, `Total` are from a `#temp` table?

Comment: @TheUser Well, that depends if you want to update that temp table or use it to update your Audit table. In the last case, I'll need to know how to join them before I can answer

Comment: I know about join lol not much but I know, inner join the audit able with #temp ON ...

Comment: @TheUser yeah, it's actually the `ON` part that I need to know

Answer (score 0):

you need not run the update on all the rows, just filter on the ones where you want to update:

```
update dbo.audit
set    aud_closedate = getdate()
where  scored + na = total
```